# Form1_KeyDown not working as per required

Tags: c#, winforms

I have taken a link button on my form and on `KeyDown` event I write as follows to move the link button to left

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            linkLabel1.Left = linkLabel1.Left + 5;
        }
    }
```

But this is not moving the linklabel as per required, can some one tell where I went wrong

This too didn't work

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                linkLabel1.Left = linkLabel1.Left + 5;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: nothing happens, but if i take a text box or some thing and I write the same event my control is moving a per required

Comment: If you remove the 'if' completely - does any key-press move the linkbutton?

Comment: I enable `KeyPreview = true;` but still it is not working for Arrow keys what I have written

Comment: You need to override the ProcessDialogKey method, see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2):

set form1`s **KeyPreview** = true.
it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think its to do with the interception of events by the linklabel.  With the link label present on the form the key down event will not be raised to the form.

Setting KeyPreview to true (on the form) goes someway towards fixing this.  You should then get the event raised, though you might still have problems with the arrow keys.

Update:

Ok, this should work, add this:

```
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            linkLabel1.Left = linkLabel1.Left + 5;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks `Justin Harvey` how can I make sure that the controls stop moving when it reaches to the end of the form

Comment: Just check the linkLabel1.Left (plus its width) against the form width in addittion to the keyData check.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to move a **Control**, you have to reconfigure it's **Control.Location** property.
So simply add or remove some dots form the Location.[X/Y].Property and that's all!

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            // have we space?
            if(linkLabel1.Location.X >= 4)
                // 5 dots to the left side
                linkLabel1.Location = new Point(linkLabel1.Location.X - 5, linkLabel1.Location.Y);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx)

Location is a **Point** and a **Point** has a (x,y) - Coordinate.

Comment: Error I am getting with ur code `Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable`

Answer (score 0):

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            linkLabel1.Left = linkLabel1.Left + 5;
        }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }